# How do I $save a new object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), it seems that it's only possible to save an existing object, not a new one. That is, there is a `$save` method on `$resource` that takes zero parameters.

How to I `POST` a **new** object to the server using `$resource`?

The documentation is severely lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Resource.save` takes the object as a parameter.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

```
var Item = $resource("/api/items/:id", {id: "@id"});
//Item is the "model", you have the method unprefixed
$scope.items = [];
$scope.addItem = function () {
  var item = Item.save({name: $scope.newItemName}); //unprefix call
  $scope.items.push(item);
  $scope.newItemName = '';
};
$scope.saveItem = function (item) {
  // item is, this time, a "Item instance" (returned by Item.save)
  // and has the functions prefixed
  item.$save();
}
```

From our chat, it seems this is enough (bare minimum) to `POST` an object:

```
$resource('/some/path').save({name: 'Fred'});
```

Comment: It's a `$resource`? Did you mean `$save` instead of `save`? How did you get the resource in the first place? What is `query`? I'm really confused. There's just no context around this.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource. `var Item = $resource('/api/items/:id', {id: "@id"});`.

Comment: It's in the action list, in the docs : "'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},"

Comment: So you're saying I have to `GET` before I `POST`?

Comment: I can't just `POST` an object without `GET`ting other objects first? That is unacceptable.

Comment: If you don't need to fetch the other resources, then no, you don't need to `.query()`

Comment: What about `Item.save` vs. `Item.$save`? The documentation uses the latter. Is it a typo or undocumented API to which I am not privy without reading the source?

Comment: let's move that discussion to a chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30622/discussion-between-user1737909-and-steve-taylor)